# What does a Ruby instance variable with a preceding colon mean (:@name)?

Tags: ruby, symbols, instance-variables

I'm working through Ruby Koans and got to question #193:

```
  class Dog2
    def set_name(a_name)
      @name = a_name
    end
  end

  def test_instance_variables_can_be_set_by_assigning_to_them
    fido = Dog2.new
    assert_equal [], fido.instance_variables

    fido.set_name("Fido")
    assert_equal [___], fido.instance_variables
  end
```

The answer is "assert_equal **:@name**, fido.instance_variables". I know the colon (:) designates a symbol and the atsign (@) designates an instance variable. However, I haven't found documentation about what a combined colon and atsign means.

What does it mean and how is it used? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It's just a regular symbol:

```
:@name
#=> :@name
:@name.class
#=> Symbol
```

According to the documentation for [`Object#instance_variables`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables):

> ## instance_variables → array
>
> Returns an array of instance variable names for the receiver. Note
>   that simply defining an accessor does not create the corresponding
>   instance variable.
>
> ```
> class Fred
>   attr_accessor :a1
>   def initialize
>     @iv = 3
>   end
> end
> Fred.new.instance_variables   #=> [:@iv]
> ```

So here Ruby Koans is saying that `fido.instance_variables` should be equal to an array containing the symbol `:@name`.

```
assert_equal [:@name], fido.instance_variables
```